# Passing props to child using map() returns undefined on second render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a list using a map function to create an array of list components. I am passing `items` prop from an external JS file. Please note I am logging `typeof(this.props.title)`.

```
//THE CHILD -- RENDERS THE LI TAG
a = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        onSelected: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired 
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(typeof(this.props.title));
        return React.createElement("li", {className:"filter_li"))
    }
}),

//THE PARENT
s = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        items: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
        var h, c, o;
        return h = {
            className: "filter_ul"
        },
        React.createElement("ul",Object.assign({},h),
            this.props.items.map(function(e,index) {
            var p = {
                key: index,
                title: e.title,
                onSelected: this._onItemSelected
            };
            return React.createElement(a, p)
        },this))
    },
    _onItemSelected: function() {
        console.log("Selected")
    }
}),
module.exports = s
```

When I run this, the log has 'string' printed 10 times as expected (there are 10 list items) but then after that 'undefined' printed 6 times -- why does this happen?

Comment: In your render function, why do you have `return h = {...}, React.createElement(...)`

Comment: @taylorc93 as an alternative to what?

Comment: I'm mostly curious what the `h` is doing, I've never seen components rendered this way.  These are the 2 ways I've seen components rendered: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding

Comment: Removed `h` to make the code simpler as it is not relevant to the error.

Comment: Are you wondering about createElement? It's what JSX is compiled to: so `return <li className= {"filter_li"}></li>` becomes `return React.createElement("li",{className: "filter_li"})`

Comment: Ahhhh, that's why.  I've never written react without JSX haha

Comment: Your parent class never passes a prop title. This code should not work at all.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks. I've corrected it. My original problem still persists.